# How to update AutoRest in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, swagger-2.0, autorest

**Context**
I would like to use AutoRest generated client for a webapi service by using "Add"/"REST API Client..." in visual studio 2017.
However, it gives the following error:

- [Info]*AutoRest Core 0.16.0.0*
- ...
- [Fatal]Error generating client model: *Collection format "multi" is not supported* (in parameter 'xxx').

The older version of AutoRest (e.g. 0.16.0) does not support "multi" collection format. So I installed the latest version AutoRest 0.17.3. using Nuget. But when I use "Add"/"REST API Client...", it still uses 0.16.0 version AutoRest and gives me the same error. It seems visual studio 2017 has a built-in AutoRest version 0.16 assembly.

**Question**
How do I get the latest version of AutoRest and integrate it in Visual studio 2017?

Comment: Seems this question was also asked on GitHub, See it here: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2198

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem so I built a tool for it called [REST API Client Code Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChristianResmaHelle.APIClientCodeGenerator). I worked in teams where we used tools like [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest), [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag), and [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate our REST API Clients and it always annoyed me that the "Add New - REST API Client..." tooling in Visual Studio didn't always work and was very troublesome when it was time to re-generate the client

[image]

The [REST API Client Code Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChristianResmaHelle.APIClientCodeGenerator) piggy backs on top of [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest), [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag), and the Java SDK for [Swagger Codegen CLI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) and [OpenAPI Codegen CLI](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). So to be able to use AutoRest you will need [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to be installed and then you need to manually install AutoRest using NPM

```
npm install -g autorest
```

Using the tool will add the Swagger.json file to the C# project and set a [custom tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/custom-tools?view=vs-2019) to it so every time the changes are made to the Swagger.json file, the API Client code is re-generated. You will have to manually update the Swagger.json file though if you use Auto, NSwag, Swagger Codegen, OpenAPI Codegen though. But if you chose to use [NSwag Studio](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio) to generate code then you can just re-generate the code directly from the .nswag file from the C# project

[image]